# If $H$ is a proper retract of $G$ of finite homological type, then $\chi (H)\lneq \chi(G)$?

Tags: group-theory

A group is said to have finite homological type if it has subgroups of finite index which have finite cohomological dimension and if every such subgroup has finitely generated integral homology.

By Brown's "cohomology of groups", the Euler characteristic $\chi (\Gamma)$ is defined for groups $\Gamma$ of finite homological type and is characterized by the following two properties:

(i) If $\Gamma'$ is a subgroup of $\Gamma$ of finite index, then $\chi (\Gamma')=(\Gamma :\Gamma')\cdot \chi (\Gamma)$.

(ii) If $\Gamma$ is a torsion-free, then $\chi(\Gamma)=\sum(-1)^i \dim_Q H_i (\Gamma ,Q)$.

If $H$ is a proper retract of $G$ of finite homological type, then $\chi (H)\lneq \chi(G)$?

Comment: Two votes to close on a perfectly fine question. One can safely bet that the voters have absolutely no knowledge about the subject, if we take into account tradition...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez To be fair, there is context to this question which would have been helpful - it, I assume, grew out of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4702418/is-there-a-function-alpha-mathcalx-to-mathbbr-for-a-class-of-groups#comment9954669_4702418) comment of mine, and in particular the comment mentions Euler characteristic but was really meaning the negative of the Euler characteristic. Then $-\chi(H)\leq-\chi(G)$, and (for example) for free groups this inequality is strict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rank 2 free group $G=\langle a,b \rangle$ properly retracts to the rank $1$ free subgroup $H = \langle a \rangle$.

But $\chi(H)=0 > -1 = \chi(G)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Dear @LeeMosher , could you please me tell me that does my statement hold when we replace Euler characteristic by krull dimension or cohomological dimension of a limit group?

Comment: That sounds like an interesting followup question. However rather than asking it here in the comments to an answer which only you (the poster) and I (the answerer) will ever see, you instead might wish to post a new question.

Comment: You are right. I will do it. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Dear @LeeMosher I asked the question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4703438/about-krull-dimension-or-cohomological-dimension-of-a-limit-group . I would really appreciate if you could help me about it. Thank you.