# About geometrical dimension or cohomological dimension of a group

Tags: group-theory

I asked: [If $H$ is a proper retract of $G$ of finite horological type, then is $\chi(H)\lneq\chi(G)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4703087/if-h-is-a-proper-retract-of-g-of-finite-homological-type-then-chi-h-lne/4703095?noredirect=1#comment9955144_4703095)

The answer was negative because the rank $2$ free group $G=\langle a,b \rangle$ properly retracts to the rank $1$ free subgroup $H = \langle a \rangle$. But $\chi(H)=0 > -1 = \chi(G)$.

A finitely generated group $G$ is called a *limit group* if, for any finite subset $S\subset G$, there exists a homomorphism $f:G \to F$ (where $F$ is a free group of finite rank) so that the restriction of $f$ to $S$ is injective.

By a cohomological dimensionof a group $G$ we mean $$cd(G)=\sup\{ n\; \text{such that}\; H^n(G,M)\neq 0,\; \text{for some}\; \mathbb{Z}G\text{-module}\; M\}.$$

A geometrical dimension, $gd(G)$, of a group $G$ is the smallest dimension of a CW-complex $K(G,1)$.

Does this statement hold when we replace the Euler characteristic by the geometrical dimension or cohomological dimension of a group (particularly a limit group)?

Comment: What examples of limit groups do you know?

Comment: And, by the way, could you recall the definition of the Krull dimension of a group? (I know the one of a variety or of a ring, or a variety over a noncommutative group, but I am not sure about the dimension of a group).

Comment: @MoisheKohan The class of limit groups is a generalization of the class of free groups. I've just added its definition. Examples of limit groups include: finite-rank free abelian groups, fundamental groups of closed surfaces with the Euler characteristic less then −1, some doubles.

Comment: @MoisheKohan sorry, I meant here "geometrically dimension" not "Krull dimension". But you can take a look at here: https://msp.org/gt/2012/16-1/gt-v16-n1-p05-s.pdf for "Krull dimension for limit groups".

Comment: Please may I suggest using $-\chi(G)$ instead of $\chi(G)$? This was a typo in my original comment to your original question (sorry!).

Comment: @Mahtab: Ok, but did you read Lauder's paper? He does not define the Krull dimension for groups either.

Comment: @user1729 I understood your idea. No problem. That is a really fine idea from my opinion. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user1729 Not completely. Very sorry. But as I said, I meant "geometrical dimension" here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finitely generated free groups are precisely the groups of cohomological dimensions $1$ (by the Stallings-Swan Theorem), equivalently geometric dimension $1$. As subgroups of free groups are free, any retract $H\neq\{1\}$ of a free group $G$ will have the same cohomological/geometric dimension, i.e.
$$\operatorname{cd}(G)=1=\operatorname{cd}(H).$$

Therefore, as free groups are limit groups, neither cohomological or geometric dimension satisfies the properties you wish.